# Can we use pattern in textarea react?

Tags: react-hooks, textarea

I need to validate textarea value and I couldn't find proper solution for it.
any sugguestions?

`<textarea onChange={(e) => valueHandler(e)} />`

`const valueHandler = (event: any) => {`
`if(event.target.validity.valid){`
`//todo..`
`}`
`}`

event.target.validity.valid is always returns true.

Comment: How are validating the field? If you have no validations it will always be valid.

Comment: As I saw many articles I didn't get any that has how to apply pattern to textarea element, so i'm going with following approach. const valueHandler=(e:any)=>{ //event.target.value match with requirements }